# Identity BlueTooth BLE device connection in multiple devices having same services and characteristics?

Tags: ios, core-bluetooth

I have multiple BLE devices which have same services and characteristics. I can scan and connect  multiple devices. After connections, tried to distinguish each one by sending command but it does not work. It works perfectly with a single device.   Is it something like socket connection ? Like A server spawns child threads and each client can maintain a connection through threads.  Please provide some tips on how to identity each device.

CBCentralManager instance I created is singleton.

```
+ (id) sharedInstance
{
    static BLEConnectionManager *this   = nil;

    if (!this)  {
        this = [[BLEConnectionManager alloc] init];
    }
    else  {
        [this scanDevice];
    }

    return this;
}

-(void) scanDevice {
    [centralManager scanForPeripheralsWithServices:nil options:0];
}

- (id) init
{
    centralManager = [[CBCentralManager alloc] initWithDelegate:self queue:nil];
    peripherals = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    [centralManager scanForPeripheralsWithServices:nil options:0];
    return self;
}
```

===
EDIT

Is this going to work?  After establishing a connection per a device,  I am going to create an instance handling service and characteristics in didConnectPeripheral delegation method like temperatureSensor example Apple provide. So each device maintains a connection separately.

```
- (void) centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didConnectPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral  
{
    service = [[[LeTemperatureAlarmService alloc] initWithPeripheral:peripheral  controller:peripheralDelegate] autorelease];
[service start];
}
```